# How to create android snackbar with custom layout

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

I'm trying to create snackbar with custom layout. Give me an example if it is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom layouts are discouraged due to the intended use of Snackbars, they're essentially "interactive toasts" and shouldn't contain anything more than a message and an action.See the [design guidelines](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/snackbars-toasts.html#snackbars-toasts-usage) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Just try with this

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
        .make(coordinatorLayout, "This is snackbar", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);

snackbar.show();
```

Or else

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
        .make(coordinatorLayout, "Message is deleted", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
        .setAction("UNDO", new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar snackbar1 = Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, "Message is restored!", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                snackbar1.show();
            }
        });

snackbar.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

[Refer This Link](https://github.com/rey5137/Material/wiki/SnackBar)

```
final SnackBar mSnackBar = SnackBar.make(getActivity()).
    applyStyle(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
    mSnackBar.text("This is SnackBar")
    .singleLine(true)
    .textSize(15)
    .textColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent))
    .actionText("CLOSE")
    .actionTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary))
    .actionClickListener(new SnackBar.OnActionClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onActionClick(SnackBar sb, int actionId) {
            // Handle click
        }
    })
    .duration(5000);
```